# Do you need Xbox LIVE for Squads in Call of Duty: Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

Before I get CoD: Ghosts I'd like to know if you need Xbox Live for Squads because I don't have Xbox Live, if it doesn't need LIVE I'll get it soon - since you can practise with your Squad on multiplayer maps. If not, I'll get it later when I have LIVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jamd, Unfortunately anything that requires online play will require LIVE.

Squads has a local play option but in order to battle against other squads not controlled by bots you will need a LIVE membership of Gold status.

Answer (score 1):

you must be Xbox live gold member to play online